# Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that $f(xf(y) + f(x+y)) = y(f(x)+1)+f(x) \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, contest-math

$
\text{Find all functions } f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } f(xf(y) + f(x+y)) = y(f(x)+1)+f(x) \text{ for every } x, y \in \mathbb{R}
$

Let $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.
By plugging $x = 0$, we get $f(f(y)) = y(f(0) + 1) + f(0)$. Since $f(f(x_1)) = f(f(x_2))$, we have $x_1(f(0) + 1) + f(0) = x_2(f(0) + 1) + f(0)$.

Therefore, $f$ is injective for $f(0) \neq -1$.

For the case where $f(0)$ is different from $-1$:

If we let $y=0$, and $f(0)=c$, then we get
$ f(cx+f(x))=f(x). $
Since f is injective in this case, $cx+f(x)=x$, or $f(x)=(1-c)x$.
Plugging back into the original function, we get
$ (1-c)^2(xy+x+y)=y(x-xc+1)+x-xc. $
We can then compare the coefficients of $y$, giving
$ (1-c)^2(1+x)=x-xc+1. $
After some simplification we get $(c^2-c)x=2c-c^2$. This is only true for all $x$ when $c=0$. Thus, $f(x)=x$ is the only solution.

$
\text{For } f(0) \neq -1, \text{ } f \text{ is bijective. By plugging } y=0 \text{ and } f(0)=c, \text{ we find that } f(x)=x. \text{ I got stuck at the case where } f(0)=-1? 
$
I think $f(x)=-1$ but I don’t know how to prove it.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Can you write out the argument for $f(x)=x$ if $f(0)\neq -1$?  As I see it, taking $f(0)=c$ and letting $y=0$ gives $f(cx+f(x))=f(x)$  How do you deduce $f(x)=x$?  It is certainly true that $f(x)=x$ is a solution...   Of course the constant  $f(x)=-1$ is also a solution.

Comment: @lulu I added the proof. Do you know how to approach the case f(0)=-1

Comment: Well...how do you know that $f$ is bijective?

Comment: @lulu we can take m, n where f(m)=f(n) and then we plug in x=0 and after some calculations we get that f is injective which is sufficient to find f(x) in this case

Comment: Please write out the entire proof.  Don't leave critical details for the comments.

Comment: @lulu is it ok now?

Comment: Yes!  That looks complete.

Comment: Note that taking $x=0$ in the case $f(0)=-1$ gives $f(f(y))=-1$ so at least $f$ is constant on the image of $f$.

Comment: @lulu I still have to prove the case where f(0)=-1 but I don’t know how to approach it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150806/discussion-between-math-enthusiast9-and-lulu).

Comment: What issues remain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle the case in which $f(0)=-1$:

We want to show that the constant function $f(x)=-1$ is the only solution in this case.

First note that taking $x=0$ in the functional equation gives us $$f(f(y))=-1$$ so $f$ is constant on it's image.

Now suppose that there was some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\neq -1$.

Taking $x=x_0$ in the functional equation gives:  $$f(x_0f(y)+f(x_0+y))=y(f(x_0)+1)+f(x_0)$$

So, under the assumption that $f(x_0)\neq -1$, we see that $f$ is surjective since, taking an arbitrary $z\in \mathbb R$ we can take $$y(z)=\frac {z-f(x_0)}{f(x_0)+1}$$  and then remark that $$f\big(x_0f(y(z))+f(x_0+y(z))\big)=z$$

Thus we get a contradiction, and we are done.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you so much!

Comment: can you please explain to me how $$f\big(x_0f(y(z))+f(x_0+y(z))\big)=z$$ gets us a contradiction?

Comment: Just write it out.  the left hand is $y(z)\times (f(x_0)+1)+f(x_0)$ and now use the defining expression for $y(z)$.

Comment: The expressions are messy, but the concept is clear. If $f(g(y))=Ay+B$ where $A$ is not $0$ then $f$ is surjective, since all non-constant linear maps are surjective. I just that observation in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume $f(t)=-1$ for all $t$, then the left-hand side of the functional equation is $-1$. But for the right-hand side, we get $y(f(x)+1)=y(-1+1)=0$. The conclusion is that $-1=0$, a contradiction. @Lulu shows that the only potential solution with $f(0)=-1$ is the constant function equal to $-1$. Hence, there is no solution with $f(0)=-1$.